# Python as web server language

Tags: python

Is it possible to write in Python as we do it in PHP? For example, I just write HTML code and write PHP code when I need it; is this possible in Python?

Comment: Check out http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/42868/how-to-use-python-as-a-server-language-from-a-php-perspective.

Comment: And how can I to achieve this? Maybe it is available something like XAMPP for Python?

Comment: Python doesn't support this out of the box, but there are lots of 3rd party modules, as suggested in the linked thread.